# Set errorlevel from batch-file

Tags: unit-testing, batch-file, testing, error-handling, scripting

I am working on this complicated (for me...) automation and one part is a batch script Started (not Called) from another one. 
Now, it's all work-in-progress and I'd like to be able to replace the Started batch script with a simple instruction that would do such that the Start-ing script, after having started the child script, has: 
%ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1
(And then I could work on the error-handling aspects and test stuff) 
But also something nice that doesn't put the system in an unnatural state (and I might script things according to that bad state and wonder why things don't work when I assemble it all). 
 So, "Format C -q" doesn't work! ;)

Thanks

Comment: I think the question should be replaced with just `How to set a nonzero errorlevel? I need it to test error handling routines in my batch file.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`cmd /c exit 1` will set the errorlevel to `1`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have user input errorlevel you can use the `choice` command.

```
@echo off
choice /c 123456789
echo %errorlevel%
```

Depending on what you type on the order of the `choice` command the errorlevel will be set starting at `1`.

example:

```
choice /c dghet
```

pressing 'd' will make the `errorlevel` 1, and pressing h will make the `errorlevel` 3. Also as a perk you don't need to press enter after the input.

Comment: That's not what I was looking for but it's very cool! Thanks!